# Add File to Table of Contents

Tags: classicthesis

```
    \documentclass[dottedtoc, headinclude, footinclude=true]{scrbook}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\mainmatter
\include{chapterzero/chapterzero}



\end{document}
```

How can I add the chapters that I am including to the table of contents?

Comment: If the file `chapterzero` includes a `\chapter` command, this chapter should be automatically listed in the table of contents, given that you use `\tableofcontents` instad of `tableofcontents` and iven that you compile your main document more than just once.

Comment: Yes, it does. I try also this "\chapter*{Remarks}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Remarks}". But it doesn't work.

Comment: We can't tell as we don't know the contents of your files.

Comment: You should be able to create an example that doesn't have `\include` or `\input` that shows the problem you're having.  See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497